# When to use Anonymous functions in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

When to use Anonymous functions in Elixir instead of named functions?

For example I have this snippet:

```
handle_open = fn
{:ok, :done} -> "OK"
{:error, _} -> "Error:"
end
handle_open.(ExAws.S3.download_file("#{Application.get_env(:ex_aws, :s3)[:bucket_s3]}", "foo.jpg", "../../public") |> ExAws.request);
```

In this case I use an anonymous function. How can I have the same result (with multibody) with a named function?

In this case is it more correct to use an anonymous or named function?

Comment: The answer of when to use anonymous functions or named ones is the same when you extract a bit of code into a new function. Why do you extract? Because you want to reuse it. If your code is smallish just define an anonymous function and use it (mostly used with functions that receive callback, such as `Enum.map`). If you need your function somewhere else, it is better to extract it into a named function. As a side note, you have assigned your anonymous function to a variable. That's something I see rarely. Use inline anonymous functions for one time use codes, and named ones for reusable ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would either do a single function with a case clause, or two function clauses, like so:

```
def handle_open({:ok, :done}), do: "OK"
def handle_open({:error, _}), do: "Error:"
```

Comment: thanks, and how can i Call it then ? I create two private function like your comment, and How can i do a pattern matching with this `ExAws.S3.download_file("#{Application.get_env(:ex_aws, :s3)[:bucket_s3]}", "foo.jpg", "../../public") |> ExAws.request`

Answer (score 2):

Usually as a parameter.

Many standard library functions in Elixir accept a function as a parameter.

For example, `Enum.map`:

```
[1, 2, 3]
|> Enum.map(fn(number) ->
  number * 2
end)
```

You could also define named function

```
def multiple_by_two(number), do: number * 2
```

And then capture it:

```
Enum.map([1, 2, 3], &multiple_by_two/1)
```

but the first way is also being used very often.

Comment: thanks denis, but When I have to use anon instead of named ?

Comment: I don't know such cases when you `have to`. It looks like they are interchangeable.